# How to get Messages sent between popup script to content script and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that involve sending request for data from popup script to Content script (through background script) analyze the request on the content script side and send back a response (again through the background script).

The popup script code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:"getLanguages",data:"hi hi",}, function(response) {
    document.write(response.msg);
});
```

The background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var returnedLangs;
    if (request.action == "getLanguages"){
        returnedLangs = getLangs();
        alert("got langs " + returnedLangs);
        //sendResponse({msg: "goodbye"});
    }

});

function getLangs() {
    var langs; 
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "getLanguages"}, function(response) {
            langs = response.langs;
            alert(langs);
            return langs;
        });
    });
}
```

The content script code:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse)
    {
        getLanguages(sendResponse,sendBackLangs);
    });

function getLanguages(sendResponse,callback) {
    var acceptLangs = [];
    chrome.i18n.getAcceptLanguages(function(langs) {
        langs.forEach( function(lang) {
            acceptLangs.push(lang);
        });
        callback(sendResponse,acceptLangs);
    });
}

function sendBackLangs(sendResponse, acceptedLangs) {
    sendResponse({langs: "acceptedLangs"});
}
```

With the current content script code no response is sent back to the background but if i do sendResponse directly from the chrome.extension.onMessage... function the response is arriving back to the background. 
Can anyone help me understand what causes ths behavior and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "getLanguages"}, function(response) {
        langs = response.langs;
        alert(langs);
        return langs; // <---- Return where?
    });
```

See the above snippet. You can't return a value from an asyncronous callback. In fact, this code block just finishes before the inner function executes and `getLangs()` returns `undefined`.

What you want to do, however, is doable. You can pass the `sendResponse` function into the callback to be called later; you just need to indicate to Chrome that you will call it later.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "getLanguages"){
        getLangs(sendResponse); // Pass the callback
        return true; // Indicates to Chrome to keep the message channel open
    }
});

function getLangs(callback) {
    var langs; 
    chrome.tabs.query(
        {active: true, currentWindow: true},
        function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                tabs[0].id,
                {action: "getLanguages"},
                function(response) {
                    // Here it sends it to the content script
                    callback(response.langs); 
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

That said, there's absolutely no reason to route the request through background. Just do the `tabs.query` directly in the popup.